# Delphi - Custom drawing a message list

Tags: delphi, drawing, custom-controls

Please refer to my question asked at tek-tips.com:
http://tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1663735&page=1

As I mentioned in a couple of my other threads, I'm building a control to pretty much replicate the SMS text messaging on the iPhone. This consists of simply a bubble on either side of the control containing text. I already have a working version, but need to re-build it from scratch. I'd like some advice on some things...

What do you think is the best method to store the list of message data? I was thinking using a TCollection, but that could be way too heavy. Currently I'm using a TStringList containing raw text data which is parsed out and translated appropriately. This works great because I don't have to create any extra objects with loads of unnecessary properties. It's just...

```
data syntax:
<user_size><deliminator><user><message_size><deliminator><message>

which could look like:
9|djjd4713023|This is a test message!

characters:
SDTTTTTTTTTSSDTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT

user_size = 9
deliminator = |
user = djjd47130
etc.......
```

Anyway, I expect possibly thousands of messages in this control. Which brings me to my next question. The best way to draw it. Currently, I'm using a TDrawGrid, and am in the process of converting it to a TStringGrid so I can contain the text directly in the grid rather than the TStringList. However that's where I stopped because I'm wondering if there's another better way than to use a grid. It's easy because it automatically manages storing the rect of each cell, etc.

How about using a TImage instead? There's another concern about the largest possible control size. This control automatically grows higher with the more messages, so again, if there's for example 1,000 messages, with an average message bubble height of about 80 pixels, that would mean the grid control needs to be 80,000 pixels high. Using a TImage though could be tough, because I would then have to manually calculate the position on that canvas to draw each balloon, similar to how grids internally keep track of that.

By the way, this grid (or otherwise canvas) is inside of a TScrollBox (final control will inherit from a TScrollingWinControl). This is how it can scroll, while the actual canvas its self is much larger than the control, big enough to draw all the message balloons. Scrolling in the control is actually moving up and down in the TScrollBox to see portions of the control canvas displaying the messages.

To summarize the pieces I need to perfect:
- Light-weight method of storing message items in a list (inside grid, string list, collection, or other list?)
- Scrollable canvas with list items of variable height (grid, image, or other list?)
- Allowing maximum number of messages to be kept with variable heights?
- Ability to customize how the control reacts to user actions to automatically scroll up or down

I'm not necessarily asking for a fix for anything, but rather advice to make it the best possible way.

Comment: What is the problem with my answer at the old Q? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719025/delphi-drawing-text-to-canvas-word-wrap-and-measuring-size

Comment: Here, you should ask a question with complete context, not just a link to another web site. Please, update.

Comment: There's not necessarily any problem with your prior post, just I"m afraid how I've built this now is extremely heavy and needs to be cleaned up. I'll repost.

Comment: The right way is to build a true custom control (descending from `TCustomControl`), doing everything manually, and *not* to rely on a combination of various VCL controls.

Comment: Yes Andreas, this is actually my point, I will be inheriting from a TScrollingWinControl. However I don't know how to properly expand the canvas inside this control in order to actually make it scrollable. Grids won't work well because it always snaps each cell to the top of the control, but this needs to scroll smoothly, assuming there may be a message which is drawn larger than the control. I'm currently building it on a form of its own just for testing/development. I will be moving it all to a component once it's perfected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I were you, I'd do something like this:

```
unit ChatControl;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Controls, Graphics;

type
  TUser = (User1 = 0, User2 = 1);

  TChatControl = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FColor1, FColor2: TColor;
    FStrings: TStringList;
    FScrollPos: integer;
    FOldScrollPos: integer;
    FBottomPos: integer;
    FBoxTops: array of integer;
    FInvalidateCache: boolean;
    procedure StringsChanged(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetColor1(Color1: TColor);
    procedure SetColor2(Color2: TColor);
    procedure SetStringList(Strings: TStringList);
    procedure ScrollPosUpdated;
    procedure InvalidateCache;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure Resize; override;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
    function DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer;
      MousePos: TPoint): Boolean; override;
    procedure Click; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Say(const User: TUser; const S: String): Integer;
    procedure ScrollToBottom;
  published
    property Align;
    property Anchors;
    property Cursor;
    property Font;
    property Color1: TColor read FColor1 write SetColor1 default clSkyBlue;
    property Color2: TColor read FColor2 write SetColor2 default clMoneyGreen;
    property Strings: TStringList read FStrings write SetStringList;
    property TabOrder;
    property TabStop;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses Math;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Rejbrand 2009', [TChatControl]);
end;

{ TChatControl }

procedure TChatControl.Click;
begin
  inherited;
  if CanFocus and TabStop then
    SetFocus;
end;

constructor TChatControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  DoubleBuffered := true;

  FScrollPos := 0;
  FBoxTops := nil;
  InvalidateCache;

  FStrings := TStringList.Create;
  FStrings.OnChange := StringsChanged;
  FColor1 := clSkyBlue;
  FColor2 := clMoneyGreen;

  FOldScrollPos := MaxInt;
end;

procedure TChatControl.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_VSCROLL;
end;

destructor TChatControl.Destroy;
begin
  FStrings.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TChatControl.DoMouseWheel(Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer;
  MousePos: TPoint): Boolean;
begin
  dec(FScrollPos, WheelDelta);
  ScrollPosUpdated;
end;

procedure TChatControl.InvalidateCache;
begin
  FInvalidateCache := true;
end;

procedure TChatControl.Paint;
const
  Aligns: array[TUser] of integer = (DT_RIGHT, DT_LEFT);
var
  Colors: array[TUser] of TColor;
var
  User: TUser;
  i, y, MaxWidth, RectWidth: integer;
  r, r2: TRect;
  SI: TScrollInfo;
begin

  inherited;

  Colors[User1] := FColor1;
  Colors[User2] := FColor2;

  y := 10 - FScrollPos;
  MaxWidth := ClientWidth div 2;

  Canvas.Font.Assign(Font);

  if FInvalidateCache then
    SetLength(FBoxTops, FStrings.Count);

  for i := 0 to FStrings.Count - 1 do
  begin

    if FInvalidateCache then
      FBoxTops[i] := y + FScrollPos
    else
    begin
      if (i < (FStrings.Count - 1)) and (FBoxTops[i + 1] - FScrollPos < 0) then
        Continue;
      if FBoxTops[i] - FScrollPos > ClientHeight then
        Break;
      y := FBoxTops[i] - FScrollPos;
    end;

    User := TUser(FStrings.Objects[i]);

    Canvas.Brush.Color := Colors[User];

    r := Rect(10, y, MaxWidth, 16);
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle,
      PChar(FStrings[i]),
      Length(FStrings[i]),
      r,
      Aligns[User] or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_CALCRECT);

    if User = User2 then
    begin
      RectWidth := r.Right - r.Left;
      r.Right := ClientWidth - 10;
      r.Left := r.Right - RectWidth;
    end;

    r2 := Rect(r.Left - 4, r.Top - 4, r.Right + 4, r.Bottom + 4);
    Canvas.RoundRect(r2, 5, 5);

    DrawText(Canvas.Handle,
      PChar(FStrings[i]),
      Length(FStrings[i]),
      r,
      Aligns[User] or DT_WORDBREAK);

    if FInvalidateCache then
    begin
      y := r.Bottom + 10;
      FBottomPos := y + FScrollPos;
    end;

  end;

  SI.cbSize := sizeof(SI);
  SI.fMask := SIF_ALL;
  SI.nMin := 0;
  SI.nMax := FBottomPos;
  SI.nPage := ClientHeight;
  SI.nPos := FScrollPos;
  SI.nTrackPos := SI.nPos;

  SetScrollInfo(Handle, SB_VERT, SI, true);

  if FInvalidateCache then
    ScrollToBottom;

  FInvalidateCache := false;

end;

procedure TChatControl.Resize;
begin
  inherited;
  InvalidateCache;
  Invalidate;
end;

function TChatControl.Say(const User: TUser; const S: String): Integer;
begin
  result := FStrings.AddObject(S, TObject(User));
end;

procedure TChatControl.ScrollToBottom;
begin
  Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_BOTTOM, 0);
end;

procedure TChatControl.SetColor1(Color1: TColor);
begin
  if FColor1 <> Color1 then
  begin
    FColor1 := Color1;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TChatControl.SetColor2(Color2: TColor);
begin
  if FColor2 <> Color2 then
  begin
    FColor2 := Color2;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TChatControl.SetStringList(Strings: TStringList);
begin
  FStrings.Assign(Strings);
  InvalidateCache;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TChatControl.StringsChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InvalidateCache;
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TChatControl.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  SI: TScrollInfo;
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_GETDLGCODE:
      Message.Result := Message.Result or DLGC_WANTARROWS;
    WM_KEYDOWN:
      case Message.wParam of
        VK_UP:
          Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, 0);
        VK_DOWN:
          Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);
        VK_PRIOR:
          Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_PAGEUP, 0);
        VK_NEXT:
          Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_PAGEDOWN, 0);
        VK_HOME:
          Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_TOP, 0);
        VK_END:
          Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_BOTTOM, 0);
      end;
    WM_VSCROLL:
      begin
        case Message.WParamLo of
          SB_TOP:
            begin
              FScrollPos := 0;
              ScrollPosUpdated;
            end;
          SB_BOTTOM:
            begin
              FScrollPos := FBottomPos - ClientHeight;
              ScrollPosUpdated;
            end;
          SB_LINEUP:
            begin
              dec(FScrollPos);
              ScrollPosUpdated;
            end;
          SB_LINEDOWN:
            begin
              inc(FScrollPos);
              ScrollPosUpdated;
            end;
          SB_PAGEUP:
            begin
              dec(FScrollPos, ClientHeight);
              ScrollPosUpdated;
            end;
          SB_PAGEDOWN:
            begin
              inc(FScrollPos, ClientHeight);
              ScrollPosUpdated;
            end;
          SB_THUMBTRACK:
            begin
              ZeroMemory(@SI, sizeof(SI));
              SI.cbSize := sizeof(SI);
              SI.fMask := SIF_TRACKPOS;
              if GetScrollInfo(Handle, SB_VERT, SI) then
              begin
                FScrollPos := SI.nTrackPos;
                ScrollPosUpdated;
              end;
            end;
        end;
        Message.Result := 0;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure TChatControl.ScrollPosUpdated;
begin
  FScrollPos := EnsureRange(FScrollPos, 0, FBottomPos - ClientHeight);
  if FOldScrollPos <> FScrollPos then
    Invalidate;
  FOldScrollPos := FScrollPos;
end;

end.
```

This is ultra-fast even with 10 000 messages.

[image: Screenshot]

To test it, do something like

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  ChatControl1.Strings.Clear;
  for i := 0 to StrToInt(LabeledEdit1.Text) - 1 do
    ChatControl1.Say(TUser(Random(2)), RandomString(2, 80));
end;

procedure TForm4.Edit2KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  Assert(Sender is TEdit);
  if ord(Key) = VK_RETURN then
  begin
    ChatControl1.Say(TUser(TEdit(Sender).Tag), TEdit(Sender).TExt);
    Key := #0;
    TEdit(Sender).Clear;
  end;
end;
```

Full source and compiled demo: [ChatControlDemo.zip](https://privat.rejbrand.se/ChatControlDemo.zip)

Still, there is certainly room for further improvements. For example, it is pretty stupid to recompute the entire cache array when you add a single message to the end of the string list. Clearly, it suffices to simply append the position of this newly added message to the cache array. But I leave that up to you.

Comment: Eureka! Thank you much, this gives me a much better idea. You didn't necessarily have to write the whole thing, but great that you did. This pretty much answers my question, appreciate it!