# How add data to a third column of ListView from of a determinated point?

Tags: delphi, tlistview

My goal here is add the info, referent to size of each file (only file) that must stay in a third column of `ListView`.

My attempt below was without success. Where is wrong?

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    LV1: TListView;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ListSize: TStrings;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function ListFolders(Directory: String): string;
var
  FileName, Dirlist: string;
  SearchRec: TWin32FindData;
  FindHandle: THandle;
  ReturnStr: string;
begin
  ReturnStr := '';

  try
    FindHandle := FindFirstFile(PChar(Directory + '*.*'), SearchRec);
    if FindHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      repeat
        FileName := SearchRec.cFileName;
        if ((SearchRec.dwFileAttributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) <> 0) then
          Dirlist := Dirlist + (FileName + #13);
      until FindNextFile(FindHandle, SearchRec) = False;
  finally
    Winapi.Windows.FindClose(FindHandle);
  end;
  ReturnStr := (Dirlist);
  Result := ReturnStr;
end;

function FileSizeStr(FileName: string): string;
const
  // K = Int64(1000);     // Comment out this line OR
  K = Int64(1024); // Comment out this line
  M = K * K;
  G = K * M;
  T = K * G;
var
  size: Int64;
  handle: integer;
begin
  handle := FileOpen(FileName, fmOpenRead);
  if handle = -1 then
    Result := 'Unable to open file ' + FileName
  else
    try
      size := FileSeek(handle, Int64(0), 2);
      if size < K then
        Result := Format('%d bytes', [size])
      else if size < M then
        Result := Format('%f KB', [size / K])
      else if size < G then
        Result := Format('%f MB', [size / M])
      else if size < T then
        Result := Format('%f GB', [size / G])
      else
        Result := Format('%f TB', [size / T]);
    finally
      FileClose(handle);
    end;
end;

function GetFiles(FileName, Ext: String): String;
Var
  SearchFile: TSearchRec;
  FindResult: integer;
  ListFiles: TStrings;
begin
  ListFiles := TStringlist.Create;
  ListSize := TStringlist.Create;
  FindResult := FindFirst(FileName + Ext, faArchive, SearchFile);
  try
    While FindResult = 0 do
    begin
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      ListFiles.Add(SearchFile.Name);
      ListSize.Add(FileSizeStr(FileName + SearchFile.Name));
      FindResult := FindNext(SearchFile);
    end;
  finally
    FindClose(SearchFile)
  end;
  Result := ListFiles.Text;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  L: TListItem;
  vListFolders, vListSize, vListFiles: TStringlist;
  i, j, k: integer;
begin

  LV1.Clear;

  vListFolders := TStringlist.Create;
  vListFiles := TStringlist.Create;
  vListSize := TStringlist.Create;

  vListFolders.Text := ListFolders('C:\');
  vListFiles.Text := GetFiles('C:\', '*.*');
  vListSize.Text := ListSize.Text;

  for i := 0 to vListFolders.Count - 1 do
  begin
    L := LV1.Items.Add;
    L.Caption := vListFolders.Strings[i];
    L.SubItems.Add('Folder');
  end;

  for j := 0 to vListFiles.Count - 1 do
  begin
    L := LV1.Items.Add;
    L.Caption := vListFiles.Strings[j];
    L.SubItems.Add('File');
  end;

  ///////////////////////////////////////

  for k := 0 to vListSize.Count - 1 do
  begin
    L := LV1.Items.Add;
    L.Caption := vListSize.Strings[k];
    // L.SubItems.Add(vListSize.Strings[k]);
  end;

  ///////////////////////////////////////

  vListFolders.Free;
  vListFiles.Free;
  vListSize.Free;
end;
```

[image]

---

**EDITION**:

> I need of handle each column singly, because these data will come of client side of my application of Remote Adminitration and is requested each data separately. First is requested **Folders** -> comes Folders, after **Files** -> comes Files, and by last the size of each file that is stored on client side of same way that was showed above. Consider the code of `Button` like my receiver (server side) :D.

Eg (Receiving folders, and after, requesting files):

```
if Pos('<|Folder|>', s) > 0 then
      begin
        s2 := s;
        Delete(s2, 1, Pos('<|Folder|>', s2) + 9);
        s2 := Copy(s2, 1, Pos('<<|', s2) - 1);
        Lista := TStringList.Create;
        Lista.Text := s2;
        // showmessage('ra');
        L2 := Form1.LV1.FindCaption(0, intToStr(Socket.Handle), false, true, false);
        (L2.SubItems.Objects[4] as TForm3).ListView1.Clear;
        // Application.MessageBox(PChar(Lista.Text), ' ', 48);
        for i := 0 to Lista.count - 1 do
        begin

          L := (L2.SubItems.Objects[4] as TForm3).ListView1.Items.Add;
          L.ImageIndex := 0;

          Sleep(10);
          L.Caption := Lista.Strings[i];
          L.SubItems.Add('Folder');
        end;

        if (L2.SubItems.Objects[4] as TForm3).ListView1.Items[0].Caption = '..' then
           (L2.SubItems.Objects[4] as TForm3).ListView1.Items[0].ImageIndex := 5;

        Lista.Free;
        Socket.SendText('<|Files|>' + (L2.SubItems.Objects[4] as TForm3).Edit1.Text + '<<|');
      end;
```

Comment: You seem to know how to add a second column. Do the exact same thing for the third column. FWIW, your code is *very* overly-complicated, and can be consolidated. Don't treat each column in a separate list/loop. Just do one single loop, and add its sub items as you go. No need to create 3 string lists for 3 columns.

Comment: But hang on, I guess I'll fire up my IDE and show you how to do this. Don't get in the habit of expecting us to re-write your code for you though...

Comment: On second thought, you have WAY more issues in your code than just that. Memory leaks. Global variables. Application.ProcessMessages. Sorry, but your code is extremely difficult to correct in a way that you'd understand.

Comment: @JerryDodge, i need of handle each column singly, because these data will come of client side of my application of Remote Adminitration and is requested each data separately. First is requested **Folders** -> comes Folders, after **Files** -> comes Files, and by last the size of each file that is stored on client side of same way that was showed above. Consider the code of `Button` like my receiver (server side) :D.

Comment: Please refer to the first two sentences of my first comment. You already know how to do it. Just repeat the same steps. And please, don't expect us to know these things. Anybody else here would answer under the assumption that this is all your code will do in the end. The fact that it comes from a server in individual request changes the entire scope of the question. Don't you think you should have mentioned this in your question, not later in the comments?

Comment: I would use tree view for this (virtual tree view, so as virtual can list view be). The rest would would be about holding a structure (model) for such view.

Comment: @JerryDodge, the question already was edited.

Comment: No, you added it at while I was writing my comment. Look at the timestamps, and your edit history, which is visible to everyone... I hope you understand the point though that adding information later is not very efficient. (also you edited your comment to say "edited", while before that edit you were basically saying as if you included that from the beginning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `GetFiles(...)` does not more than add two values to two different TStringlist at the same time.

```
function GetFiles(FileName, Ext: String): String;
    ...
    ListFiles.Add(SearchFile.Name);
    ListSize.Add(FileSizeStr(FileName + SearchFile.Name));
    ...
```

You can add it to the Listview direct

```
var
  ListFiles: TStrings;
  ListSize : TStrings;
.....
.....

function GetFiles(FileName, Ext: String): String;
Var
  SearchFile: TSearchRec;
  FindResult: integer;
  cCount    : Integer;
begin
  Result     := 'NOT NEEDED';
  cCount     := LV1.Items.Count -1;

  FindResult := FindFirst(FileName + Ext, faArchive, SearchFile);
  try
    While FindResult = 0 do
    begin

      inc(cCount);
      LV1.Items.Add;
      LV1.Items[cCount].Caption := SearchFile.Name;
      LV1.Items[cCount].SubItems.Add('File');
      LV1.Items[cCount].SubItems.Add(FileSizeStr(FileName + SearchFile.Name));
      // C:\ + SearchFile.Name

    FindResult := FindNext(SearchFile);
    end;
  finally
    windows.FindClose(SearchFile)
  end;
end;
```

If you necessarily want to do it in the `procedure TForm1.btn1Click(...)`

```
var
  ListFiles: TStrings;
  ListSize : TStrings;
.....

.....

function GetFiles(FileName, Ext: String): String;
Var
  SearchFile: TSearchRec;
  FindResult: integer;
begin
  FindResult := FindFirst(FileName + Ext, faArchive, SearchFile);
  try
    While FindResult = 0 do
    begin
      ListFiles.Add(SearchFile.Name);
      ListSize.Add(FileSizeStr(FileName + SearchFile.Name));
      FindResult := FindNext(SearchFile);
    end;
  finally
    windows.FindClose(SearchFile)
  end;
  Result := 'NOT NEEDED';
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vListFolders : TStringlist;
  i, j, cCount : integer;
begin
  ListFiles    := TStringlist.Create;
  ListSize     := TStringlist.Create;
  vListFolders := TStringlist.Create;

  LV1.Items.Clear;
  try   
    vListFolders.Text := ListFolders('C:\');
    GetFiles('C:\', '*.*'); // Add to ListFiles, ListSize Name and size  

  // Old Only for folders ...
  // ========================================

    for i := 0 to vListFolders.Count - 1 do
    begin
      L := LV1.Items.Add;
      L.Caption := vListFolders.Strings[i];
      L.SubItems.Add('Folder');
    end;

  // New for name and size
  // ========================================
    cCount := LV1.Items.Count -1;

    if ListFiles.Count = ListSize.Count then
    begin

     for j := 0 to ListFiles.Count - 1 do
     begin
        Inc(cCount);
        LV1.Items.Add;
        LV1.Items[cCount].Caption := ListFiles[j];    // File Name
        LV1.Items[cCount].SubItems.Add('File');       // File
        LV1.Items[cCount].SubItems.Add(ListSize[j]);  // Formatted Size
     end; // for j

    end else begin
        Inc(cCount);
        LV1.Items.Add;
        LV1.Items[cCount].Caption := 'File List BROKEN';
    end;

  finally
    vListFolders.Free;
    ListFiles.Free;
    ListSize .Free;
  end;

end; // btn1Click(...)
```

Comment: I chose not to answer this question because it would only continue to encourage extremely poor coding practice. This answer isn't much different. What would actually be learned here?

Comment: Also, how did PHP come into the picture? Is there something you know about this particular OP that nobody else knows? How would that be useful to SO?

Comment: I guess OP gets data via a script from the Server. e.g. `Socket.SendText('<|Files|>' + (L2.SubItems.Objects[4] ...` from OP `EDITION :`

Comment: Before you complain to one, just 28 days member, what OP does all wrong. Look at your initial questions. And how happy you were when you were helped. `Eureka! Thank you much, this gives me a much better idea. You didn't necessarily have to write the whole thing, but great that you did. This pretty much answers my question, appreciate it!` [Delphi - Custom drawing a message list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7779808/1322642)

Comment: I fail to see your point. That was 2011, when the rules of SO were much more loose. That's 7 years worth of rule changes. They didn't even have the same close options then. They've changed since then. Why dig up the past anyway? You seem to have spent quite a bit of time doing so. I was about to write the solution for OP, but there were far too many other issues that I decided it wasn't worth the effort. Because most of what I would have answered would have been not acknowledged (as is a very common trend here).

Comment: And OP obviously knows how to add data to a column in a list view. The second column was populated just fine. I said repeatedly to do the same thing for the third column. Which seems common sense to me. I was also agitated that the entire scope of the question changed since the original reading of it. I see it as a "Fix my extremely broken code for me" type of question, which aren't useful for future readers of the site. Which is the whole purpose of this site.

Comment: Really the PHP not is part of my project, the answer was the solution simply because is able of make the task of add size of each file to side of each filename like i requested above (see image on question) and also changed idea to send to server side (Delphi) **ListFiles** + **ListSize** only in a unique request and not singly likei thinked before (see my edition).

Comment: @KKK : I have removed the PHP part. Thanks for letting me know. 2) Better to send in a unique request as you do now.