# Delphi "UI updating" issue of content provided by a thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I'm writing a small Delphi 10.3 VCL Win32 application for viewing a bunch of SVG images.  Yes, there must be application that does exactly what I want but I'm using this as a bit of a learning opportunity.

It renders each image and a label indicating the image name so you can quickly scroll through them.

I decided to thread it so the user doesn't need to wait until all the images have been loaded.

This was nice except that the main form isn't painting or processing user "messages" while the loading occurs.

I'm calling the method below via the thread's Synchronize( ) method.

```
procedure TFinderThread.CreateControlsForNextItem;
var
  img: TcxImage;
begin
  svg:=TdxSmartImage.Create;
  svg.LoadFromFile(m_slFiles[0]);
  m_slFiles.Delete(0);

  // omitted:  TLabel creation

  img := TcxImage.Create(m_owner);
  img.Left := 0;
  img.Top := m_iNextControlTop;
  img.Picture.Assign(svg);
  img.Parent := m_parent;
  m_iNextControlTop:=m_iNextControlTop + img.Height;

  svg.Free;
end;
```

I'd like the main form to be responsive and usable while it's being loaded.  I found that a short call to Sleep( ) in the thread's Execute loop makes the UI responsive.

the Execute method contains this loop:

```
m_iNextControlTop:=0;
while m_slFiles.Count>0 do
  begin
    if Terminated then
      break;

    Synchronize(CreateControlsForNextItem);
    sleep(1);
  end;
```

**The problem**

If you use the scroll bar during refresh, some controls don't appear at all in the scroll box.  The objects exist, are visible, have the correct parent, etc.  This is doesn't change if you later scroll around so it doesn't appear to be a "painting" issue.  It's as though the scrollbox doesn't recognize them as content.

If you don't scroll at all during refresh, all the images will appear correctly.

Any idea what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: This design is inherently flawed. Your idea is to use a separate thread that performs work while the GUI thread is handling the GUI. That's good, but: when you call `Synchronize`, the GUI thread will perform the given routine. So if your thread *only* does `Synchronize` calls, it is entirely pointless: it's like having only the GUI thread (but with more overhead). What you need to do is to separate the non-GUI computations from the GUI update. Do the non-GUI things in a separate thread, and then only update the GUI rarely.

Comment: Also, you must use `try..finally` blocks to protect object instances.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Andreas.  I realize it's not the most useful application for threading.  In fact, it's the creation of controls that makes it slow.  There isn't anything else worth doing in the thread if the UI parts were put in the main thread.  How would you improve the responsiveness of the UI?

Comment: Creating lots of controls to display lots of images tends not to work well. You'd be better off doing the painting directly and not using image controls at all

Comment: I'd begin by determining what the time-consuming part of the process is. But I think David is right: do you create a hundred or even a thousand controls? Then, don't do that. As you know, at any given time, you will only need to display a few of those. Only load and display those. The most sound thing to do is to do what David suggests: forget about using image controls and draw on the form's canvas manually using the `OnPaint` event. Implement a scrolling mechanism with on-demand loading of new images manually. This makes the task much more advanced, but it very much is the right thing to do

Comment: This chat control demo might get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7783559/282848

Comment: Thank you both; virtualizing it was a great (and easy) solution.  @DavidHeffernan, perhaps you could post that as an answer.  It performs wonderfully now.  Thanks!

Comment: You know the number of pictures. So create the controls in the main thread with captions says : loading in progress and then create threads to fill controls up with usefull contents. And the very end of the threads call synchronize to repaint its (injected) control.