# Making a control similar to Delphi Object Inspector (FMX)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to make a visual control similar to Delphi Object Inspector, where clicking on > will expand the properties, example, click on Font will expand to Color, Height Edit box etc, or clicking on a set will reveal 4 rows with properties fsbold, fsitalic checkboxes etc.

What is the best control to achieve this?  I know I can reference some projects which has Vcl object inspector, but which base control should I start with in FMX?

Comment: There is no native base control like the OI in either VCL or FMX. But there are plenty of 3rd party solutions, if you don't want to make your own from scratch.

Comment: ok, I know there isn't but since Delphi itself has it, I'm sure they built it from a base control... I know fmx has a third-party vendor that has it, but my needs are very simple, so if I can built a similar functionality - mainly I need the parts with the ">" property to expand appropriately and show more properties or checkboxes (for sets) - may not be exactly the same visually, that'll be good enough.  will TTreeview or something else be the best component to start with?

Comment: I would build my own control from scratch (from `TCustomControl`) if this was VCL. Building your own control isn't particularly difficult, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779808/delphi-custom-drawing-a-message-list, https://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/controls/tageditor/readme.html etc.

Comment: @PeterJones "*since Delphi itself has it, I'm sure they built it from a base control*" - the OI is a completely custom UI written from scratch just for the IDE's exclusive use. The closest native control to the OI would be something like `TValueListEditor`, but that is VCL-only, has limited customizations, and doesn't have expansion capabilities. I've heard of people making custom OIs out of grids, trees, etc. There is no 1 single way to approach this problem. But FMX does have better support for nesting controls than VCL, so I'm sure you can come up with something, if not a 3rd party solution

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thanks for the info. was hoping to use an existing suitable control and do the necessary nesting.