# How to draw text on a canvas with left alignment?

Tags: delphi, shapes, delphi-2010

I want to draw a rectangle on a canvas and I want to fill it with text. I've tried with the below code, but it only succeeded with right alignment.

Can anyone help me? How can I draw text on a canvas with left alignment?

```
{Header Table}
SetStyleHuruf(FCanvas, fsBold, 12, clWhite, 'Maiandra GD');
Brush.Color := color;
Rectangle(cx+50, cy-50, cx+370, cy - 30);
TextOut(round(cx + 215), cy-50, Name);`
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image. Just paste the code into the question, mark the code and press ctrl-k.

Comment: Stop adding 215 to cx (which pushes it to the right). Also stop subtracting 50 from cy. It also helps if your first step to understanding the use of a function or method is reading the documentation, so that you know what the parameters are that you're passing.

Comment: i have a problem with create a table in canvas

Answer (score 2):

Look at the definition of `TextOut`:

```
procedure TextOut(X, Y: Integer; const Text: string); override;
```

The description in help says:

> Writes a string on the canvas, **starting at the point (X,Y)**, ...

So, modify your code to draw the text at an X coordinate that is closer to the left border of the rectangle instead of the right right. For example:

```
TextOut(round(cx + 215), cy-50, Name);
```

Outputs the text 5 pixels from the left border of the rectangle

```
TextOut(round(cx + 55), cy-50, Name);
```

BTW, assuming `cx` is an integer, you dont need to use `Round()`

Comment: Oh, I thought I did. Please, explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of textout I would use DrawText function which is explained on the Microsoft site [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The DrawText function draws formatted text in the specified rectangle. It formats the text according to the specified method (expanding tabs, justifying characters, breaking lines, and so forth).
>   To specify additional formatting options, use the DrawTextEx function.

Here you find a great [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719025/calculating-size-of-text-before-drawing-to-a-canvas) how to use it

Comment: In recent versions of Delphi, `TCanvas` in VCL has a overloaded [`TextRect()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.TextRect) method that wraps `DrawText()` and exposes its flags as a `TextFormat` parameter.